# How to create a Visualforce Page for the Apex Class queried to Account & Opportunity count value details?

Tags: apex, visualforce

i have the below page requirement to create,

[image]

Below is my Apex Controller Class,

```
public class AccountOppsCountWithOwner {
    public Map<String, List<AggregateResult>> getAccountsAndOppsWithOwners() {
        Map<String, List<AggregateResult>> aggResultsMap = new Map<String, List<AggregateResult>>();
    
        AggregateResult[] accountResults = [SELECT Count(Id), Owner.Name FROM Account GROUP BY Owner.Name ORDER BY Owner.Name]; 
        AggregateResult[] opportunityResults = [SELECT count(id), Account.Owner.Name FROM Opportunity GROUP BY Account.Owner.Name ORDER BY Account.Owner.Name];   
    
        aggResultsMap.put('accounts', accountResults);
        aggResultsMap.put('opportunities', opportunityResults);
    
        return aggResultsMap;
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a VF Page but no success, i tried as below, Need suggestion where i went wrong ?

```
<apex:page Controller="AccountOppsCountWithOwner" >
    <apex:pageBlock title= "Account & Opportunity Details">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accountResults}" var="acc">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!opportunityResults}" var="opp">
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Owner.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Count(Id)}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!opp.Count(Id)}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Its throwing an error while saving,

> Unknown property 'AccountOppsCountWithOwner.accountResults'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to combine your data into a single collection. For this, I'd recommend a wrapper class. The wrapper class should contain all the properties you want:

```
public class Wrapper {
    public String ownerName { get; set; }
    public Integer numberOfAccounts { get; set; }
    public Integer numberOfOpportunities { get; set; }
}
```

Next, you will want two or three queries. Since we're not doing a lot here, I opted for three in my design. First, we get the number of accounts, then opportunities, then the user's name. Note that we use Id values to make sure we get values for owners that may have the same name.

```
public Wrapper[] getAccountsAndOppsWithOwners() {
    Map<Id, Wrapper> results = new Map<Id, Wrapper>();
    for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT COUNT(Id)accountCount, OwnerId FROM Account GROUP BY OwnerId]) {
        Wrapper item = new Wrapper();
        item.numberOfAccounts = (Integer)result.get('accountCount');
        results.put((Id)result.get('OwnerId'), item);
    }
    for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT Count(Id)oppCount, OwnerId FROM Opportunity GROUP By OwnerId]) {
        Id ownerId = (Id)result.get('OwnerId');
        Wrapper item = results.get(ownerId);
        if(item == null) {
            result.put(ownerId, item = new Wrapper());
        }
        item.numberOfOpportunities = (Integer)result.get('oppCount');
    }
    for(User record: [SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Id = :results.keySet()]) {
        results.get(record.Id).ownerName = record.Name;
    }
    return results.values();
}
```

Now, to address your Visualforce code, note that something like `{!record.count(id)}` wouldn't be valid. It'd have to be written as `{!record['expr0']}` to access the values dynamically. We get around this by instead using a wrapper class, which simplifies our code considerably. Here's the updated code:

```
<apex:pageBlock title="Owner Info">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AccountsAndOppsWithOwners}" var="ownerInfo">
        <apex:column value="{!ownerInfo.ownerName}" headerValue="Owner Name" />
        <apex:column value="{!ownerInfo.numberOfAccounts}" headerValue="Number of Accounts" />
        <apex:column value="{!ownerInfo.numberOfOpportunities}" headerValue="Number of Opportunities" />
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked, but only one issue, on the line where " If (item==null), result.put(ownerId, item = new Wrapper()); " Here, its showing an error on AggregateResult value ( Error was due to an inactive User in SF). I put teh try and catch exception and it worked. may i know plz , whats the mean of this line? If, item==null, the line "  result.put(ownerId, item = new Wrapper());" What exactly it signifies ?